# Efficient way of calculating the arc length of a parameterized curve?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

give me the curve :I am asked for the arc length between 0 and 2 (although I think it is between 0 and 2Pi) and it gives as a result 100

```
  x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
  y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t];
```

after deriving y with respect to t , and squaring and putting all of that into a root I arrive at this :

(*when using the interval from 0 to 2 ,it comes out *)

```
50*NIntegrate[Sqrt[(-2 + t)^2 Cos[t]^2 + ((-3 + t) Cos[t] + Sin[t])^2], {t, 0, 2}]
```

(*150.102*)

(*when using the interval from 0 to 2Pi,it comes out *)

```
50*NIntegrate[Sqrt[(-2 + t)^2 Cos[t]^2 + ((-3 + t) Cos[t] + Sin[t])^2], {t, 0, 2Pi}]
```

(*559.51*)

in none of the cases did I reach 100, then
the result of the text is wrong?
I made a mistake that I do not see?
is there a better way for MMA to solve the problem?

Please help me

Comment: `ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` ?

Comment: Look at `FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 1}]`

Comment: it strikes me as weird that `y` is `50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t]`, since that can be simplified to `50 (3 - t) Sin[t]`. maybe you transcribed it incorrectly and one of those should be a `Cos` or something? (also I realized you'll want `N @ ArcLength[...]`

Comment: Ok, yeah, changing it to `y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t]` and looking at `ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, 2}]` gets you `100` even without `N`!

Comment: Thank you all, I did not write the equations wrong, they must be wrong from the beginning, if I was doing everything right I did not know why I did not get the result, thanks for all your indications, I learned a lot today, very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the arc length for the parametrized curve given by:

```
p[t_] = {x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t],
   y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t]};
```

for t=0 to t=2. Let's first make a plot to get an idea what we are dealing with:

```
ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Therfore we expect an arclength of about 150.

The differential of p[t], used to get the arclength element,  is:

```
dp[t_] = D[p[t], t];
```

With this, the differential arclength is:

```
dl[t_] = Sqrt[dp[t] . dp[t]];
```

and the arclength:

```
NIntegrate[dl[t], {t, 0, 2}]

(* 150.102 *)
```

**Addendum**

With the change of the formula:

```
p[t_] = {x = 50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t], 
   y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t]};

ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

We get for the arc length:

```
dp[t_] = D[p[t], t];
dl[t_] = Sqrt[dp[t] . dp[t]];
NIntegrate[dl[t], {t, 0, 2}]

(* 100. *)
```

Comment: thanks , thorimur discovered an error in the "y" of the curve ( there goes a cos (t) at the end ) with that modification changes the figure , I learn from here how to draw parametric curves , thanks , you could take the opportunity to correct it also

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, you proposed this FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 1}] and I find it great before the correction made by thorimur to the y , which is y = 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Cos[t], but I try to use your same argument to check that for t=2 the area is 100 , but it doesn't work , I wrote it like this; FindRoot[ArcLength[{x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}] == 100, {tmax, 3}], because the root to find is supposed to be inside that environment, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `NIntegrate[dl[t], {t, 0, 2}]` works under the assumption that `p[t]` does not go back-and-forth on the curve ;)

Comment: @ A.G. As p[t] is a parametrized curve and not p[x], it can as many time  back-and-forth as it want.

Comment: I added the changed curve to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArcLength` function works fine, although it takes a few seconds to run.

````
$Version
l[x_PositiveReal] = 
   ArcLength[{50 (1 - Cos[t]) + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t], 50 Sin[t] + 50 (2 - t) Sin[t]}, 
             {t, 0, x}]
N[l[2]]
(* 
"12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"

Integrate[
  Sqrt[2500 (2-t)^2 Cos[t]^2 + (50 Cos[t] + 50 (2-t) Cos[t] - 50 Sin[t])^2], 
  {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> 0 < x]

150.102
*)
```
````